# Docker run printing wrong answer

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-run

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y figlet
WORKDIR /app
COPY scriptas.sh /app/scriptas.sh
CMD figlet "NEDAS KAIRYS MKDF-23/1"&& chmod +x /app/scriptas.sh && ./scriptas.sh && ls darbas
```

this is script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
rm - fr darbas
mkdir darbas
for i in $(find /etc -name '*.conf')
do
dydis=$(du -b "$i" | cut -f1)
vardas=$(basename "$i")
cp -r "$i" "darbas/${dydis)_${vardas}"
done
```

when i run this script using docker run i get diffrent answers compared to when i run it only using script. Hope you understand what i mean since i dont know the exact terminology

it supposed to print around couple hundred files but it only prints around 30

Comment: That script would fail with a syntax error. Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it'll tell you about (e.g. `for i in $(find /etc -name '*.conf')` is an anti-pattern) and then post your shellchek-clean script if you still need help.

Comment: `rm - fr` is wrong

Comment: It's been a while but based on what I THINK I remember from using docker ... `/etc` inside your docker container isn't the same directory as `/etc` outside of it, you probably need to define a `volume` if you want `/etc` from outside to be accessible inside the container.

Comment: You have to fix 2 things. 1st "rm -fr" (remove the space after hyphen), and the second one is you have to mount /etc of the OS inside docker container. Ex: add the command "-v /etc:/etc" while your are running your container.

Comment: Share us the  "different answers" and what is the expected!